# Prove that the order of homomorphic image divides the order of the group without using First Isomorphism Theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G'$ is a homomorphic image of $G$.
Let $\phi:G\rightarrow G'$ be an epimorphism.
We want to show that $|G'|$ divides $|G|$.

It can be done easily by using the concept of cosets, quotient group and also First Isomorphism Theorem. But this exercise appears under the subtopic homomorphisms so those contents are not involved yet.

From what I know, there is an identity that is
$$|G|=|\ker \phi||G'|$$
But I have no idea how to prove it.
Does this mean that the epimorphism will partition image of $G$ into $G'$ classes where each class have $|\ker \phi|$ elements?

I just write my answer in a proper way.
Since $\phi$ is surjective, the pre-images of every element in $G'$ will partition $G$. That is,
$$|G|=\sum_{y\in G'}|\phi^{-1}(y)|$$
Let $y\in G'$
Then $y=\phi(x)$ for some $x\in G$ due to the surjectivity.
Hence, $|\phi^{-1}(y)|=|\phi^{-1}(\phi(x))|=|x\cdot \ker \phi|=|\ker \phi|$.
This proves the identity.

Comment: Do you mean $\phi(G)$ rather than $\phi(G')$?

Comment: @Nex $G'$ sorry typo

Comment: In essence the reason this is true is that the equivalence classes of the equivalence relation defined by $g_1\sim g_2$ if and only if $\phi(g_1)=\phi(g_2)$ are all bijective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means it indeed. Here is a self contained proof – which amounts more or less to prove the 1st isomorphism theorem:

> **Lemma:** For any $g\in G$, we have $\phi^{-1}\bigl(\phi(g)\big)=g\cdot\ker\phi$.

This means  any $h$ such that $\phi(h)=\phi(g)$ has the form $h=gx$, for a (unique) $x\in\ker \phi$.

Indeed, $\phi(gx)=\phi(g)\phi(x)=\phi(g)e'=\phi(g)$ ($e'$ is the unit of $G'$). Conversely, if $\phi(h)=\phi(g)$, we have $\phi(g^{-1}h)=\phi(e)=e'$, so $x=g^{-1}h\in ker \phi$  and $h=g(g^{-1}h)$.

Since $\phi$ is surjective, this proves $G$ is partitioned into the  subsets  $\phi^{-1}\bigl(\phi(g)\big)$ which all have cardinality  $m=\lvert\ker g\rvert$. If $r$  is the number of elements in this partition, we have 
$$\lvert G\rvert=\underbrace{m+m+\dots+m}_{r \text{ terms}}=mr$$
by the *shepherd's principle*.

Comment: I can understand the lemma but still can't get the point how $G$ is partitioned into the subsets. And how to link this with $G'$?

Comment: And also $|G|\neq \sum_{g\in G}|\phi^{-1}(\phi(g))|$ right? since the mapping is not injective.

Comment: The subsets are the inverse images of the elements of $G'$. For your second question: you're right. This is because if $h\in \phi^{-1}\bigl(\phi(g)\big)$, then $\phi^{-1}\bigl(\phi(h)\big)=\phi^{-1}\bigl(\phi(g)\big)$ For this reason of duplicates, I speak of the *set* of $\phi^{-1}\bigl(\phi(g)\big)$, not of the *family*.

Comment: I have updated my idea above. Can you please check whether my thought is correct? Thanks!

Comment: Two observations: 1) I would say ‘ the pre-images of the elements in $G'$…’, as it is not one pre-image alone which partitions $G$. 2) After `hence` it should be $\phi^{-1}(y)$. The end of this line supposes you have enunciated the lemma (you may call it lemma, claim or whatever you want, but you have to state it for a full justification).

Answer (score 1):

As $\phi$ is an epimorphism then it is a surjective homomorphism. As such $\operatorname{im}\phi=G'$ which is the subgroup of $G'$ that, since $\phi$ is an epimorphism, is the whole of $G'$, and $\ker\phi=K$, where $K$ is the subgroup of $G$ whose elements map to $1_{G'}$, the identity in $G'$.

Since we have an epimorphism: 
$$|G|=|\operatorname{im}\phi||\ker\phi|=|G'||\ker\phi|$$
and $G$ is thus partitioned into $\frac{|G|}{|K|}$subsets all of order $|\ker\phi|$ which map to $G'$ under $\phi$.