# Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of finite group $G$. Prove that if order of $H$ and order of $G/N$ are relatively prime then $H$ is a subgroup of $N$.

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

> Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of finite group $G$. Prove that if order of $H$ and order of $G/N$ are relatively prime then $H$ is a subgroup of $N$.

Can someone help me to understand the intuition behind this question and why is this happening with example?

I am basically clueless about how to start.

Comment: What is the order of $\pi(H)$, where $\pi:G\to G/N$ is the projection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the first isomorphism theorem, the order of a homomorphic image of a group divides the order of the group.

Consider the canonical projection $π:G\to G/N$.  Then $|π(H)|\mid|H|$.

And by Lagrange, $|π(H)|\mid|G/N|$.

So $π(H)=0$.  So $H\le N$.

Comment: We have not been taught the theorems of isomorphism yet so I presume that we are supposed to solve it without using isomorphism theorems..

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1937048.